# Pygame text input not on screen

Tags: python, text, pygame, user-input

I need to kb input onto a pygame screen
at the moment it appears on the idle shell
any advice would be appreciated.

This code is extracted from a larger program
mostly screen based but i need to input some
data (numeric) from the kb at times

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

N= ''
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
font= pygame.font.Font(None,40)
screen.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.display.flip
pygame.display.update()


def score(C,y):
    SetWnd = font.render( C,True,(0,0,255))
    screen.blit(SetWnd, (15, 100+y))
    pygame.display.update()


def start():
    while True:
        name=''

        for evt in pygame.event.get():
                if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if evt.unicode.isalnum(): # unicode
                        name+=evt.unicode
                        print name,

                    elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                            name = name[:-1]
                            print name,
                    elif evt.key == K_RETURN:
                        return N
                elif evt.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
def Pchange(c,y):
    block = font.render(N, True, (0,0,0))
    rect = block.get_rect()
    rect.move_ip(75,100 + y)
    screen.blit(block,rect)
    pygame.display.flip()



score('wind', 0)
score('elev',20)

N = start()
Pchange(N,0)
Pchange(N,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you draw the score twice, which i assume works well.

The problem lies in you start function.
You are not calling any draw or update function in your while loop.
In your event foreach, you add a digit to `name`, and exit the while loop when enter is pressed. Then you draw twice with Pchange, but you are the function does not use the right parameters. You have:

```
def Pchange(c,y):
    block = font.render(N, True, (0,0,0))
```

you are using the global N which is ''. So to fix that, you need to change `N` to `c`.

The next problem is that the game quits right after pressing enter. Since you pasted only a part of the program, this might not be the case. If it is, make another while loop, and just wait for the ESC key to call `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()`

Comment: many thanks   yes there is more that exits the prog correctly the N instead of c was a copy typo---  still have the problem that input is only on the shell not printed after wind  & elev

Comment: you can edit your question, so we will be able to see the problem better.